# How to add mongoose db for auto increment?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I want add in auto increment for my model class in mean stack. How I do bellow class?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sampleApp'); 

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', {
    email : { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    password : { type: String}
});
```

Comment: which field you want to increment

Comment: add new field and increment.

Comment: [check this StackOverflow example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199482/create-unique-autoincrement-field-with-mongoose) or use [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment)

Comment: but this isn't work for me.

Comment: did you tried using  mongoose-auto-increment?

Comment: The big question is: why do you need this? There is a unique identifier in each mongo document, `_id`. You can most likely use this for whatever it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: yes @CodeBean but not working.

Comment: @Joost  Vunderink I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Try creating a user, retrieving it, then `console.log(user._id);`.

Comment: console.log(user._id); anser is 56826787f6c830381416572e.