# Generate auto increment field using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a database which consist of four fields id, text, key, status. I want to add another field named order which consist of a number, which is representation of the order. I also have functionality to delete documents so after deletion order will not be continuous, i also want to have order continuous and non repeating. If some documents are deleted from db order is adjusted automatically based on the number of documents in database.I have two files index.js and items.js. I have used mongoose, body-parser and expressjs.

My order field is non repeating and continous.

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

Items = require('./items.js');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/taskDb');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send('Visit /api/*****');
});

app.get("/api/items", (req, res) => {
    Items.getItems(function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});

app.post("/api/items", (req, res) => {
    var item = req.body;
    console.log(item + "item post");
    Items.addItem(item, function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});

app.delete("/api/items/:_key", (req, res) => {
    var key = req.params._key;
    Items.deleteItem(key, function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});

app.delete("/api/items/", (req, res) => {
    var status = "completed";
    Items.deleteItems(status, function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});

app.put("/api/items/:_key", (req, res) => {
    var key = req.params._key;
    var item = req.body;

    Items.updateItem(key, item, {}, function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});

app.put("/api", (req, res) => {
    Items.updateAllItem(function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});

app.listen(3005, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3005...');
});
```

items.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    key: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    order: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

var Item = module.exports = mongoose.model('item', itemSchema);

module.exports.getItems = function (callback, limit) {
    Item.find(callback).limit(limit);
}

module.exports.addItem = function (item, callback) {
    Item.create(item, callback);
}

module.exports.deleteItem = function (key, callback) {
    var query = { key: key };
    Item.remove(query, callback);
}

module.exports.deleteItems = function (status, callback) {
    var query = { status: status };
    Item.remove(query, callback);
}

module.exports.updateItem = function (key, item, options, callback) {
    var query = { key: key };
    var update = {
        text: item.text,
        key: item.key,
        status: item.status
    }
    Item.updateOne(query, update, {}, callback);
}

module.exports.updateItem = function (key, item, options, callback) {
    var query = { key: key };
    var update = {
        text: item.text,
        key: item.key,
        status: item.status
    }
    Item.updateOne(query, update, {}, callback);
}

module.exports.updateAllItem = function (callback) {
    console.log("Update All");
    Item.update({}, { $set: { "status": "completed" } }, { "multi": true }, callback);
}

module.exports.changeItemsOrder = function (items, callback) {
    var query = Item.remove({}, callback);
    assert.ok(!(query instanceof Promise));

    // A query is not a fully-fledged promise, but it does have a `.then()`.
    query.then(function (doc) {
        // use doc
    });

    // `.exec()` gives you a fully-fledged promise
    var promise = query.exec();
    assert.ok(promise instanceof Promise);

    promise.then(function (doc) {
        // use doc
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create unique autoincrement field with mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199482/create-unique-autoincrement-field-with-mongoose)

Comment: The answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 11):

You can use this library for increment your order field: [Mongoose Sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-sequence)

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);

  var ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    key: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    order: {
      type: Number
    }
  });

  ItemSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {id:'order_seq',inc_field: 'order'});
  var ItemModel = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);

  let newItem1= new ItemModel({
    text:'text1',
    key:'key1',
    status:'A'
  });
  newItem1.save();

  let newItem2= new ItemModel({
    text:'text2',
    key:'key2',
    status:'A'
  });
  newItem2.save();

  let newItem3= new ItemModel({
    text:'text3',
    key:'key3',
    status:'B'
  });
  newItem3.save();
```

Now when you create a new Item the **order** field will be incremented by the library:

[image: Auto Increment Field]